# как записать результат fetch в state Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

Нужна помощь в выполнении простой операции - запись результата fetch в store Redux.
При маунте файла postlist.js данные из fetch запроса должны записываться в state, но ничего не происходит(даже action не стреляет в интсрументах разработчика.
Заранее благодарю
файл fetch.js

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const fetchAllPosts = () => {
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/posts`).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
};
```

файл operations.js

```
import { fetchAllPosts } from '../../fetch/fetch';
import actions from './actions';

export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(actions.fetchPostRequest());
  try {
    const posts = await fetchAllPosts();
    dispatch(actions.fetchPostSuccess(posts));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(actions.fetchPostError(error));
  }
};

файл actions.js

import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const fetchPostRequest = createAction('fetchPostRequest');
const fetchPostSuccess = createAction('fetchPostSuccess');
const fetchPostError = createAction('fetchPostError');

const filterItem = createAction('filter');

export default { filterItem, fetchPostRequest, fetchPostSuccess, fetchPostError };
```

файл store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createReducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import actions from './actions';

const postReducer = createReducer([], {
  [actions.fetchPostSuccess]: (_, action) => action.payload,
});

const error = createReducer(null, {
  [actions.fetchPostError]: (_, action) => action.payload,
});

const filterReducer = createReducer('', {
  [actions.filterItem]: (_state, action) => {
    return action.payload;
  },
});

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: postReducer,
  filteredPosts: filterReducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

файл postlist.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as operations from '../redux/operations';
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
export default function PostList() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    operations.fetchPosts();
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
 </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел проблему - вызов useEffect был написан с ошибкой. Корректная подпись:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(operations.fetchPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);
```